# Passing data from route to router-view body

Tags: vue.js, parameter-passing, vue-router

I have a single page application with the structure below.

```
|- App.vue
|- + Views  
|  |- Page.vue  
|- + Components  
|  |- Slider.vue
```

EDIT 1: Solution thanks to @gengar.value
I solved the issue by passing params from `Page.vue` with

```
 methods: {
    emitIndex: function (index) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "visualization",
        params: { imgCat: "visualization", imgIndex: index },
      });
    },
  }
```

`App.vue` containing the `router-view` container that is routing the `Page.vue`
`Slider.vue` is a component of `App.vue`

I want to pass index of clicked image and whole images data from `Page.vue` to `App.vue` then to `Slider.vue` in order to achieve decoupling Slider from Page for reusability purposes.

How can I pass user selected index from `Page.vue` too `App.vue`

I have tried to use, `params`,  `props` and `emit` but failed.

Sample `Page.vue`

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in 3" :key="index"></div>
</template>

<script>

export default ({
    data() {
        return {
            urls: ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: Solution thanks to @gengar.value

Problem solved by pushing params to router via `Page.vue` and listening it from `Slider.vue` as follows:

`Page.vue`

```
 methods: {
    passIndex: function (index) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "visualization",
        params: { imgCat: "visualization", imgIndex: index },
      });
    },
  }
```

`Slider.vue`

```
watch: {
    "$route.params.imgCat": function (val) {
      this.state = val;
    },
    "$route.params.imgIndex": function (newVal) {
      if (newVal != -1) this.imgState = newVal;
      this.$router.push({ params: { imgIndex: -1 } });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a https://jsfiddle.net/  with your test code?

Comment: Hi, I do not know how to add router and component structure on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Use this as a template and fork it. https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gould-4kgoz?file=/src/main.js

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little bit complicated, but quite native since I only used Props and Emit.

You want to pass value between brother components, so you could simply try below:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Page :data="data" @syncData="syncData" />
    <Slider :data="data" />
  </div>
<template>

<script>
import Page from './Views/Page.vue'
import Slider from './Components/Slider.vue'

export default ({
  components: {
    Page,
    Silder
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: []  // init data in the parent component
    }
  },
  methods: {
    syncData(updatedImages) {
      this.data = updatedImages
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Page.vue

```
<template>
  <div></div>
<template>

<script>

export default ({
  props: {
    data: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectImage(images) {
      this.$emit('syncData', images) // update selected data to App.vue
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Slider.vue

```
<template>
  <div></div>
<template>

<script>

export default ({
  props: {
    data: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      handler(val) {
        // when Page.vue emits updated data to App.vue,
        // App.vue will pass data to Slider.vue
        // and you could receive the updated data 'val' here
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Update: Sorry I misunderstood before. If you are using vue-router components and assigned different paths (eg. '/page' and '/slider'), you can use

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/path', query: selectedImage })
```

in Page.vue and get url query in Slider.vue.

Alternative methods could be using Cookie.js or sessionStorage (not pretty tho). Also you could try Vuex if the specific condition suits you.

Comment: Missing `syncData` function in App.vue. `onSelectImage` click event not set in `Page.vue`. You're not passing the index of the selected image to `Slider.vue`. OP said he tried using emit, but couldn't make it work. I'm pretty sure he needs help with the tiny details of how to make this work. He isn't looking for an outline.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. However, I cannot declare `Page.vue` as component it is routed object. I do not want to use it in template but directly listen its emit.

Comment: @bassxzero You are right. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Mimayuki Then I think you can use this.$router.push({ path: '/path', query: selectedImage }) in Page.vue and get url query in Slider.vue if you are routing different path for both components.

Comment: I have pushed query, in `Page.vue`. However, I cannot see the changes on development environment. Does it have to be in a router file?

Comment: @Mimayuki You need to use vue-router and config routes in router.js. Someting like `import Router from 'vue-router'` and then `export default new Router({ routes: [ { path: '/page', component: Page }, { path: '/slider', component: Slider } ] })` in main.js. Then you can push $router with query and lead you to redirect within routes.

Comment: Thanks to your previous comment, I had to solve the issue by passing `params` and listening it from `Slider.vue` if you send answer post I can mark as it solved. Thanks again. :)